# docker unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-compose, dockerhub

I'm on windows 10 pro, using docker for windows, using linux containers 
i have logged in using `docker login -u username -p password`
and i'm getting this issue alot, not just with httpd but also with django, mysql .. etc

```
> docker container run -p 8080:80 -d --name n2 httpd
Unable to find image 'httpd:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/httpd
3d77ce4481b1: Downloading
73674f4d9403: Download complete
d266646f40bd: Download complete
ce7b0dda0c9f: Download complete
01729050d692: Download complete
014246127c67: Download complete
7cd2e04cf570: Download complete
docker: unauthorized: authentication required.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Just as a note, you don't need to login in order to pull public images from dockerhub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this issue update windows to winver 1803 (the new April Spring Creators update)